# Using reactive forms in Angular with services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm tryng to make a kind of deckBuilder, i have some cards and decks made of cards, these are the card and deck models

```
export class Card {
  public name: string;
  public manaCost: number;
  public imagePath: string;

  constructor(name: string, manaCost: number, imagePath: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.manaCost = manaCost;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
  }
}
```

and deck

```
import { Card } from '../card/card.model';

export class Deck {
  public deckName: string;
  public deckClass: string;
  public deckCards: Card[];

  constructor(deckName: string, deckClass: string, deckCards: Card[]) {
    this.deckName = deckName;
    this.deckClass = deckClass;
    this.deckCards = deckCards;
  }
}
```

this is the deckService file

```
import { Deck } from './deck.model';
import { Card } from '../card/card.model';


export class DeckService {

  decks: Deck[] = [

    new Deck("Control Priest", "Priest", [
      new Card("Reno Jackson", 6, "../../assets/img/Reno_Jackson.png"),
      new Card("Abomination", 5, "../../assets/img/Abomination.png"),
      new Card("Blade Flurry", 4, "../../assets/img/Blade_Flurry.png"),
      new Card("Felfire Potion", 6, "../../assets/img/Felfire_Potion.png")
    ]),
    new Deck("Big Spell Mage", "Mage", [
      new Card("Reno Jackson", 6, "../../assets/img/Reno_Jackson.png"),
      new Card("Abomination", 5, "../../assets/img/Abomination.png"),
      new Card("Blade Flurry", 4, "../../assets/img/Blade_Flurry.png"),
      new Card("Felfire Potion", 6, "../../assets/img/Felfire_Potion.png")
    ])
  ];

  newDeck: Deck; // this is undefined when i try to log it


  constructor() {

  }

  getDecks() {
  return this.decks.slice();
}

  addCard(card: Card){
    console.log(this.newDeck)       // why can't access to newDeck? i have to 
                                    //    bind this function? if i log 'this'  
                                    //   i get DeckService as expected
    this.newDeck.deckCards.push(card);

}

addNewDeck(deck: Deck){
  console.log(this.decks);
  this.decks.push(deck);
};

}
```

i have a reactive form in which i can add cards to a deck choosing the card with a selection,
i want to use the newDeck to save the cards from the form and then push the newDeck in the decks array, but newDeck is undefined, is this a binding problem?
this is the form .ts file where i use the deckservice

```
import { Deck } from './../deck/deck.model';
import { DeckService } from "./../deck/deck.service";

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { CardService } from "../card/card.service";
import { Card } from "../card/card.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-create-deck",
  templateUrl: "./create-deck.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./create-deck.component.scss"]
})
export class CreateDeckComponent implements OnInit {
  cards: Card[];
  classes = [
    "Priest",
    "Mage",
    "Shaman",
    "Rogue",
    "Warrior",
    "Warlock",
    "Druid",
    "Paladin"
  ];

  createDeckForm: FormGroup;
  deckName: FormControl;

  constructor(
    private cardService: CardService,
    private deckService: DeckService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cards = this.cardService.getCards();
    this.createDeckForm = new FormGroup({
      deckName: new FormControl("Meme Deck"),
      deckClass: new FormControl(),
      deckCards: new FormControl()
    });
  }

    onAddCard(){
      this.deckService.addCard(this.createDeckForm.value);     //this is wrong but the problem is that i can't access to newDeck


    }

  onSubmit() {

    this.deckService.addNewDeck(this.createDeckForm.value);

  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code in StackBlitz ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knmgel?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: there are some difference, i tried a couple of things like using deckService to get the newDeck but the problem is the same, just replace the StackBlitz code with the question one if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

```
newDeck: Deck;
```

you just declare the member, but don't initialize it. Therefore its value is `undefined`.
Use:

```
newDeck: Deck = new Deck(....); // .... are correct values according to its constructor.
```

instead.

Additionally have a look at this: https://dev.to/satansdeer/typescript-constructor-shorthand-3ibd

Inside your `deck.service.ts` in line 23 in stackblitz you could use

```
newDeck: Deck = this.decks[0];
```

alternatively and it would work, too.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i don't know if i have to open another question but i have another problem, this is the .html of the form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form [formGroup]="createDeckForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <label >Deck Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="deckName"
        formControlName="deckName"
        class="form-control"
      />
      <p>

      </p>
      <hr>
      <label for="deckClass">Deck class</label>
      <select id="deckClass" formControlName="deckClass">
        <option
            *ngFor="let class of classes"
            [value]="class">
            {{class}}
      </option>
      </select>
      <hr>
      <label for="deckCards">Select a Card</label>
      <select formControlName = "deckCards" id="deckCards" name="deckCards">
        <option
            *ngFor="let card of cards"
            [ngValue]="card">
            {{card.name}}
      </option>
    </select>

      <button (click) = "onAddCard()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Card</button>
      <hr>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have 2 buttons, one for adding cards to the deck and the onSubmit one to add the deck in the deck array but when i click on the addCard one it is like i'm pressing the submit one too

Comment: is this the right way to add a click listener in the html in Angular reactive forms?

Comment: by default, the buttons are of type submit. So you need to add the type attribute like so:  ```type="button"``

Comment: and yes. you need to open a new question for unrelated issues. however, what I've written in the previous comment it will fix your issue.